# Merging partially overlapping polygons into a table in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, merge

I have a couple of tables (three) with polygons (landuse coverage in this case). Within each table, there is no overlap, but between tables there might be a lot of overlap.

I would like to combine the polygons from the tables into a single table with polygons with no overlap. To resolve situations where the source tables overlap, I would like to put a priority on each layer, so that polygons from the layer with highest priority is used for the overlap.

One way to visualize what I want to do is drawing the tables on top of each other, discarding already drawn polygons where there is overlap. You could also say I want to merge the three tables into one. (Please inform me if there is some more appropriate terminology to describe what I want to do.)

A big issue in this case is performance: each of the tables contain millions of polygons.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ST_Intersects` to detect when there is overlap between the geometries of two tables. For instance, the set of polygons returned by this query would be the set you want to insert into a new, "combined" table, **assuming that** `polygons1` **is the "higher-priority" table**:

```
SELECT p1.geom
  FROM polygons1 p1, polygons2 p2
 WHERE ST_Intersects(p1.geom, p2.geom);
```

To insert the remaining polygons of the low-priority `polygons2` table, simply take the difference. I use `DISTINCT` here because you will get back every geometry in `polygons2` **for each** geometry in `polygons1` that they do not intersect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.geom
  FROM polygons1 p1, polygons2 p2
 WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(p1.geom, p2.geom);
```

So, you can either use the first query to identify overlapping low-priority polgyons to delete **or** use it to find overlapping high-priority polygons to save and insert the difference from the second query.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm looking through the documentation and I have a question: in order for the overlap to return true, does it have to overlap completely? The `dma` table would not overlap cleanly with the `states` table.

Comment: They do not have to overlap completely. [From the docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html), `ST_Intersects` "Returns TRUE if the Geometries/Geography "spatially intersect in 2D" - (share any portion of space)." It goes on to say, "For geography -- tolerance is 0.00001 meters (so any points that close are considered to intersect)."